# Azure region based WebApi for mobile app

Tags: azure, cdn

I'm currently developing a mobile app which will be pushed world-wide across the app stores.  This app uses a WebAPI REST service as the backend which I currently have running on MS Azure in Europe (which backs onto a database also in Europe).

My problem is, I'd like to create multiple Azure WebApi endpoints (i.e. Australia, US, etc for latency reasons), each with their own database which has geo-replication enabled.

Does anyone know a method/product/service I could use which allows me from the app to either:

1. Connect to a single domain which behind the scenes picks the closest server to the user.

OR

2. The app itself is able to determine based on a given list the closest server and connect to that?

I've looked at Azure CDN but this is for static content which is great but I need something for dynamic content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at is Traffic Manager. Traffic manager enables that exact scenario, of finding the closest service that hosts your REST API.

Keep in mind though, that the database replication is (for the time being) a thing you have to do yourself, although we do provide you with the tooling and guidance on how.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for much for your help.  It was sitting right under my noise but I didn't even realise Traffic manager was for this.